# Proving monotonicity of a function without using the concept of continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $2|x-y|\ge|f(x)-f(y)|\ge |x-y|, \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$ , can it be proved without using the result " every continuous injective function on $\mathbb R$ is monotone on $\mathbb R$ " that this function $f$ is monotone ?

Answer (score 3):

(Getting another old question off the unanswered list.)

It is indeed possible to prove the result without invoking continuity.

For convenience say that a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is *good* if $2|x-y|\ge|f(x)-f(y)|\ge|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$. For future reference note that it is easy to check that if $f$ is good, so are the functions $g(x)=f(x+a)+b$ for any $a,b\in\Bbb R$, which translate $f$ horizontally and vertically, and the functions $g(x)=-f(x)$ and $g(x)=f(-x)$, which reflect $f$ in the $x$- and $y$-axes, respectively.

We want to prove the following

> **Theorem:** Every good function is monotone.

Much of the work is done by the following lemma.

> **Lemma:** Let $f$ be a good function such that $f(0)=0$, and suppose that $f(b)<0$ for some $b>0$; if $x>b$, then $f(x)<0$.
>
> **Proof:** Suppose first that $b<x<3b$, and to get a contradiction suppose further that $f(x)\ge 0$. Since $f$ is good, we have
>
> $$x=|x-0|\le|f(x)-f(0)|=f(x)\,,$$
>
> $$b=|b-0|\le|f(b)-f(0)|=-f(b)\,,$$
>
> and
>
> $$f(x)-f(b)=|f(x)-f(b)|\le 2|x-b|=2(x-b)\,,$$
>
> so $x\le f(x)\le 2(x-b)+f(b)\le 2(x-b)-b=2x-3b$. But then $x\ge 3b$, which is absurd, so we must have $f(x)<0$.
>
> Now suppose that $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, and $f(x)<0$ whenever $b<x<3\cdot 2^kb$. Then $f\left(2^{k+1}b\right)<0$, so the argument in the previous paragraph ensures that $f(x)<0$ whenever $2^{k+1}b<x<3\cdot 2^{k+1}b$. It follows that $f(x)<0$ whenever $b<x<3\cdot 2^{k+1}b$ and hence by induction on $k$ that $f(x)<0$ for all $x>b$. $\dashv$

The theorem can now be proved by contradiction.

> **Proof of Theorem:** Let $f$ be a good function, and suppose that $f$ is not monotone; then there are $a,b,c\in\Bbb R$ such that $a<b<c$, and either $f(a)>f(b)<f(c)$, or $f(a)<f(b)>f(c)$. In the latter case we may replace $f$ by the good function $-f$, so we may in fact assume that $f(a)>f(b)<f(c)$.
>
> Now $|f(c)-f(a)|\ge|c-a|>0$, so either $f(a)<f(c)$, or $f(a)>f(c)$. In the latter case we may replace $a$ by $-c$, $b$ by $-b$, $c$ by $-a$, and the function $f$ by the good function $x\mapsto f(-x)$ and further assume that $f(b)<f(a)<f(c)$.
>
> But then $0<b-a<c-a$, and $g(x)=f(x+a)-f(a)$ is a good function such that $g(0)=0$ and $g(b-a)=f(b)-f(a)<0<f(c)-f(a)=g(c-a)$, contradicting the lemma, and it follows that $f$ must in fact be monotone. $\dashv$